# USB to Serial Adapter Does Not Start agetty (Centos/RedHat) Linux

Tags: linux, serial-port

I'm trying to get a terminal to work over a USB to Serial Adapter cable (PL2303 Prolific). The USB to Adapter cable works with my Windows Machines. I have a terminal (IBM 3151) for my Linux system, and it works fine over the Serial port /dev/ttyS0, using 'exec /sbin/agetty -L /dev/ttyS0 9600 dumb' in the /etc/init/serial-ttyS0.conf file.

When I plug the USB-to-Serial adapter into a USB port, it shows up as /dev/ttyUSB0 on the system. But, I can't seem to get the system to notice and start agetty on the device. I created a file /etc/init/serial-ttyUSB0.conf, and it contains...

```
start on stopped rc RUNLEVEL-[2345]
stop on starting runlevel [016]
respawn
pre-start exec /bin/stty -F dev/ttyUSB0 9600
exec /sbin/agetty -L /dev/ttyUSB0 9600 dumb
```

The system does not seem to be triggering this file, when I plug in the USB-to-Serial adapter. I can manually start agetty with...

```
$ stty -F /dev/ttyUSB0 9600
$ /sbin/agetty -L /dev/ttyUSB0 9600 dumb
```

And, then I can login with my terminal over the USB-to-Serial adapter.

Any suggestions on what I should do to get agetty to start when I plug in the USB-to-Serial adapter cable?

I'm running Centos 6.0 (RedHat 6.0) kernel 2.6.32-71.e16.i686.